# Flash Soft Bricked Locked Nexus 6P

Tags: boot-loop, bootloader-lock

How can I get my soft bricked Nexus 6P working again?

I don't mind flashing it, losing all data etc. I'd rather have it done now than send it away to be *fixed*.

It's caught in a boot loop where it only makes it to the white Google logo, then restarts. I can get to the bootloader and occasionally I can get to stock recovery mode.

Running `adb oem device-info` returns:

```
(bootloader)    Device tampered: false
(bootloader)    Device unlocked: false
(bootloader)    Charger screen enabled: false
(bootloader)    Display panel:
OKAY [  0.058s]
finished. total time: 0.058s
```

Running `fastboot flashing unlock` returns:

```
...
FAILED (remote: oem unlock is not allowed)
finished. total time: 0.021s
```

What is my next step here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In case anyone else has a similar problem, I send the phone away to get repaired and the problem was that the power button was stuck, causing the phone to turn off.

Answer (score 1):

I think your bootloader is locked you need to get the unlock key from the manufacturer website i have done it on sony phones to look at an example visit the sony developer site and read as much as you can to understand better what is going on